# UICollection view cell with large text problem

Tags: ios, swift, autoresize

I have a cell with description(`UILabel`) and two buttons after the description I use this to get the description text height

```
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.height)
```

but the problem is when I do any action on the buttons with a huge description cell the actions is not trigged this is a ver annoying a problem and tried a lot of solutions but nothing works any help ?

this is where I set the height for cells

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


    if self.items.count < 1 {
        return CGSize(width: (self.view.bounds.width - 16), height: 200)
    }
    if indexPath.item < self.items.count {
        let item = self.items[indexPath.item]
       var h = CGFloat(0)
        h = item["description"].stringValue.height(with: (self.collectionView.bounds.width - 44), font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: self.contentLabelFontSize)!)
        self.descriptionHeight = h
        if item["images"].isEmpty == false {
            if item["images"][0]["original"].stringValue != "" {
                let hi = 300
                let im_h = CGFloat(hi)
                    h += im_h
            }
        }

        if self.type == "events" {
            h += 260
        }
        else if item["type"].stringValue == "event" {
            h += 250
        }
        else {

            h += 170
        }
        let size = CGSize(width: (self.view.bounds.width - 16), height: h)
        return size
    }
    return CGSize(width: (self.view.bounds.width - 16), height: 50)
}
```

And this is where is set the height of label at the `PostCell` class :

```
  self.contentLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 110, width: (self.bounds.width - 20), height: (self.bounds.height - self.imageHeight - 170))
```

Comment: I guess, you are using auto layout to add UILabel and Buttons on cell. Also can you show your CollectionView's `sizeForItemAt indexPath` method? have your tried set background color for your description label and check, if the label overlaps on buttons?

Comment: Can share the screenshot for how the UICollectionViewCell is designed

Comment: @Natarajan yes I have tried this and it'd doesn't overlaps

Comment: @Natarajan and @ Sateesh check post updates ,

Comment: It seems you have imageView too in your cell, Can you show your PostCell code where you designing your view either programmatically or XIB?

Comment: @Natarajan  self.imageButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.bounds.height - self.imageHeight - 50), width: self.bounds.width, height: self.imageHeight - 10) the image height is fixed and always 300

Comment: the weird thing is when I print the height from the calculation its always 19.0 despite its taken height 1350 on the screen and its showed correctly on the screen .

Comment: is there a different uint or something ?

Comment: If you set masks to bounds in your cell as like `self.layer.masksToBounds = true`, you might see the cell with 19.0 height.

Comment: where do you print height? As per sizeForItemAtIndexPath function, height should be 50 or 200 or >= 170.

Comment: no ignore this comment , I printed the height they are nearly same but I do ceil the value so if it 1324.8000000000006 it becomes in the contentLabel height is 1325

Comment: do you think one pixel can ruin the all post clicks ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184472/discussion-between-natarajan-and-marcel-adel).

Comment: is there any update as the problem still exists :(